# C# .net Update Page After x Minutes

Tags: c#, html, asynchronous, timer, updatepanel

I'm trying to update an HTML table with new values after a page is already rendered. The new values are presented in the "10 min" column for the HTML table.

These are the same values presented in the "Now" column, however they should remain fixed when presented in the "10 min" column.

The following code is determining how many minutes is required before the "10 min" column is rendered.

```
    timeStart = market[0].marketStartTime;
    timeNow = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);

    timeTenMinToStart = timeStart.Subtract(timeNow).TotalMinutes - 10;
```

This is then repeated for the "1 min" column.

I have been trying to accomplish this with a timer but haven't been successful.

*Market.aspx.cs*

```
    public string getTableData()
    {
        length = market[0].runners.Count; //determine length of table
        int lengthTable = length;
        int marketCounter = 0;
        string htmlStr = "";
        while (lengthTable > 0)
        {
            htmlStr += "<tr><td> <font color=\"red\">" + market[0].runners[marketCounter].runnerName + "</text></td>" + "<td>" + marketOdds[0].runners[marketCounter].lastPriceTraded.ToString() + "</td>" + "<td>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + TenMin????() + "</td></tr>";
            lengthTable--;
            marketCounter++;
        }

        return htmlStr;

    }
```

*Market.aspx*

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">   
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <p>

    <table border="1" class="accountInfo">
    <tr >
        <td width="300px"> <b>ID</b> </td>   
        <td width="50px"> <b>Now</b> </td>      
        <td width="50px"> <b>10 min</b> </td> 
        <td width="50px"> <b>1 min</b> </td>    
        <td width="50px"> <b>Change</b> </td>                                 
    </tr>   
         <%=getTableData()%>
    </table>

    </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Refresh" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let:

```
public void MY_FUNCTION_TO_DELAY ()
{
    // your code here
}
```

... be your code that you wish to delay.

You can include this static method somewhere in your application:

```
public static void DelayMe(Action myVoidMethod, TimeSpan delayTime)
{
    Func<bool> f = () => { myVoidMethod.Invoke(); return false; };
    System.Threading.Timer t = default;
    t = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
    {
        if (!f())
        {
            t.Dispose();
        }
    }, null, default(TimeSpan), delayTime);
}
```

... Then, to trigger the function delay (for 1 minute in this case):

```
DelayMe(InitializeTradeHistory, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

... note, for the adept reading this, the static method can be modified quickly into a "repeatMe" instead of "delayMe" function.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Use [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I've only just started with programming.

Comment: Updated to include example use.

Comment: How do you keep the returned value constant when refresh is clicked?